# ¿Son los 2d NumPy array realmente homogéneos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Tengo el siguiente 2D array:

```
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> np_df =np.array(df) 
>>> np_df_0_5=np_df[0:5] 
>>> print (np_df_0_5) 
[[2136855 'HE' nan 'Hembra' 135 4054 150716349 150716349 150716349 'Vivo' 'Trazado' 'No' '20/12/2006']
 [2136856 'HE' nan 'Hembra' 135 4054 150716349 150716349 150716349 'Vivo' 'Trazado' 'No' '20/12/2006']
 [2136877 'HE' nan 'Macho' 135 4054 150716349 150716349 150716349 'Vivo' 'Trazado' 'No' '20/12/2006']
 [2136879 'HE' 'NO' 'Macho' 135 4054 150716349 150716349 150716349 'Vivo' 'Trazado' 'No' '20/12/2006']]
```

Cuando pregunto por el tipo de datos obtengo lo siguiente:

```
>>> type(np_df_0_5[0][0]) 
int 
>>> type(np_df_0_5[0][1]) 
str
```

Por lo tanto hay dos tipos de datos en el array, ¿cómo puede suceder? Estoy haciendo un curso (Python for Data Science) y me enseñan que NumPy hace iguales todos los datos, si existen strings por ejemplo, todos los datos serán transfomados en string:

> "you define different types of data in the array, but numpy array will treat them as one data type. if you have defined an array with float, string and a Boolean, that will treat it as a string as float and Boolean is converted to string."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un array de NumPy (`numpy.ndarray`) efectivamente es homogéneo en cuanto al tipo de dato, es decir, solo puede contener un tipo de dato y, por tanto, todos los items ocupan el mismo espacio en memoria.

Vamos a crear un ejemplo basado en el caso que presentas:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np


>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [2136855, 213687],
                       "b": ['HE', 'HE'],
                       "c": [np.nan, np.nan],
                       "d": ['Hembra', 'Macho']})
>>> ar = np.array(df)
```

Efectivamente si imprimimos los tipos del dato "almacenado" en cada posición parece que lo anterior es falso:

```
>>> type(ar[0][0])
<class 'int'>
>>> type(ar[0][1])
<class 'str'>
>>> type(ar[0][2])
<class 'float'>
```

Lo que ocurre es que en la construcción del array se itera sobre el DataFrame y ante la presencia de cadenas Python, ante esta situación se convierte todo a objetos Python y el array se dedica simplemente a almacenar referencias a los mismos. El array solo almacena por tanto direcciones de memoria a los objetos Python correspondientes, pero estos objetos no están almacenados en las direcciones de memoria contiguas que conforman dicho array, solo sus referencias.

Si imprimimos el tipo del array:

```
>>> ar.dtype
dtype('O')
```

nos confirma esto, `"O"` viene de `Object`, indica que el contenido son objetos nativos Python. En Python todo son instancias de alguna clase (objetos), por lo que pueden ser cualquier cosa, desde un entero, una cadena, un diccionario a una función, otro array de NumPy, una lista o una instancia de una clase propia, etc

El array es efectivamente homogéneo, almacena las referencias a objetos Python ([PyObjects](https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/structures.html#c.PyObject)), es decir cada item ocupa 4 bytes en sistemas de 32 bits y 8 bytes en sistemas de 64:

```
>>> ar.itemsize
8
```

Es decir, en `ar[0][0]` no hay un entero en realidad, date cuenta que el tipo no es un entero de NumPy como `uint8`, es entero de Python.

```
>>> foo = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype="uint8")
>>> foo.dtype
dtype('uint8')
>>> foo.itemsize
1
```

En este último ejemplo, `foo` es un array que almacena enteros de 8 bits sin signo, y en este caso el array si que contiene los tres números en posiciones contiguas de memoria, ocupando por tanto 3 bytes.  En tu ejemplo en cambio lo que hay en `ar[0][0]` es una referencia a un objeto `int` y no el entero en si mismo, en `ar[0][1]` una referencia a un objeto `str`, etc. En este aspecto actúa de forma muy similar a como lo hace  una lista de Python (`list`), las cuales se limitan también a almacenar referencias).